# Should I layout my academic paper in one or two columns?

Tags: academic-writing

Many scientists obtain papers in electronic format and read them on a computer, tablet, or mobile phone screen. In print, a two column layout looks great and is easier to read than a broad single column, but on any electronic device navigating over two columns is difficult and irritating.

So when I layout my own paper, should I lay it out in one or two columns?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about writing.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Writers. Please take our tour and see our help center http://writers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic to see what kinds of questions the community can help you with.

Comment: Flavio, I edited your question to make it on topic for this site. If this edit does not reflect the aim of your question, roll back to your original version on this page: http://writers.stackexchange.com/posts/25496/revisions

Comment: @what: Note that while the edited question may be on-topic and theoretically answerable, it is rather pointless as the format is dictated by the publisher, at least in all journals I am aware of.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft There is a growing tendency to self-publish studies with no or negative results to counter publication bias.

Comment: do both? i.e. have a original with some plain text markup (latex, org-mode, markdown, ...) and then export using two profiles?

Comment: Thank you for rephrasing my question. I should also ask: has anyone found tools for converting two-column pdf to one-column?

Comment: The idea of providing both one and two-column formats for a printout is great, latex allows one to do it quite easily. But I find lot of two-column pdf scientific papers which are difficult to read by a pc.

Comment: Interesting question. IMHO this is on topic, but Academia.SE might be more helpful. Here's the first question related to this topic I've found; perhaps that will help you find your answer: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/18729/why-do-some-elsevier-journals-use-a-single-column-format/18738#18738

Comment: If you do both, consider also telling LaTeX to format the one-column version to a smaller page size (a5 or even a6).  That way the fonts will be readable on a small screen, and lines will not be excessively long.  Limiting line length is main benefit of 2-columns, and it actually makes zooming feasible, even if panning from column bottom to 2nd column top is inconvenient — whereas 1-column on a wide page means zooming requires panning across _every single line_, completely impractical!

Answer (score 1):

Publishers have traditionally used 2 column layout for printed articles. These have then been turned into pdfs.

Okay, nowadays, some things only appear electronically. However, you, me and most of the rest of the world find them hard to read even if using a large computer screen. Reading them on things like phones is difficult.

Therefore it makes sense to lay out your work in the most readable form. Why you would publish it in two columns is beyond me. Make it easy for the reader and then they are more likely to read, and cite, your work.

In answer to a comment: there are various pdf editors. However, I haven't found one that will accurately edit a pdf it didn't create unless the layout is very simple e.g. no header or footer, no page number, no title, only one column, etc. I usually find it is quicker to turn them into text and re-format, or just re-type the whole thing (something I do quite regularly).

Comment: I  agree with S. Mitchell's comment. I read scientific papers with formulas. Unfortunately converting pdf with formulas is nowadays impossible.